# Is it ok to execute many SQL database request in the same HTTP request

Tags: sql, node.js, performance, http, backend

I am working on a chat application, but when ever a chat messages sent 3 or 4 request to database will be executed I fell like this may not be a good practice.
I execute the following

- Check if there is a chat room between two users.

if there is

- create 1 chat for user 1  "so each user will have a copy of the chat message"
- create 1 chat for user 2  "so each user will have a copy of the chat message"
- Update last message in the chat room

if not

- create chat room for the user that don't have “ each user should have a chat room"
- create 1 copy chat for user 1
- create 1 copy chat for user 2
- Update last message in the chat room.

And more request could be executed if the both of uses don't have a common chat room

Is this bad or ok, what are your thoughts ?

This is my db model
[image]

Comment: looks like poor db design, shouldn't need multiple copies of the same row so its an xy problem, to make messaging structure create the thread row when either user a sends to b, store both user ids as columns, to read back select the thread row which has your user id in any of the 2 columns, select the messages for the thread, when adding a message row use the thread id to link everything in.. max 2 querys on adding a new message

Comment: @LawrenceCherone
Please check my db model I added it

Answer (score 1):

I consider it *good practice* to make all database changes that belong together in one request, because if you make several requests, only some of them may be executed by the server (the others get lost over the internet, for example), and then only parts of the necessary changes are actually executed on the database and you have data inconsistencies.

In the same vein, even within one request you should guard against the danger that only some of the changes are executed on the database (the others get lost because the database connection breaks). You achieve this by performing all changes in one *database transaction*, through database commands like `begin` and `commit` or by encapsulating all create/update statements in one *database procedure*. Details will depend on the database (and the database client library) that you use.

Comment: Please check my db model I added it